# Auto fill hex values without a helper column

Tags: excel

I am creating a spreadsheet with multiple columns of hex values and I would like to be able to auto fill their values by dragging as I can with decimal values.  For example, if the first two rows in a column contain FFFFFF00 and FFFFFF04, I would like to be able to drag it down two rows and see FFFFFF08 and FFFFFF0C.

Of course, excel treats everything as a decimal value by default, so if you try to do what I mentioned above you will end up with the values FFFFFF08 and FFFFFF12.

I found a workaround to this using `=DEC2HEX()` where I use a helper column to supply the offset, as seen below. This works fine, but I have to have a helper column for every sequence of hex values I want auto filled.

[image]

Is there any easier way to auto fill hex values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found Excel only does math in Decimal.  So change the values to decimal do the math and change back to hex.

In the third cell put:

```
=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(A3)+HEX2DEC(A3)-HEX2DEC(A2))
```

Then drag down.

[image]